# Readonly view of an editable form with values as plain text

Tags: javascript

How to convert a form into readonly view by calling a function? I don't want to show the values in a disabled input field but as plain text.
i am using javascript for achieving it.

Comment: So the question is "how do I use the contents of an input field as the text content of an element (and also destroy or hide the input field)?" Is that correct?

Comment: What have you tried?  You can dynamically create elements, show/hide existing elements, etc.  Where exactly are you stuck?  There's no built-in function for this, if that's what you're asking.  You'd have to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Fields doesn't have to be disabled, thay might be readonly as well, you would just need to iterate through all the input fields, apply readonly property and perhaps some css class that will make them look more like plain text rather than input field.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'), i;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  inputs[i].classList.add('input-readonly');
  inputs[i].setAttribute('readonly', true);
}
```

proof of concept:
https://jsfiddle.net/4rkn5qda/

PS: You will also have to take under consideration other type of fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this using jQuery:

```
var myform = $('.myform')
myform.find('input').each(function() {
    var currentEl = $(this),
        currentVal = $(this).val();
    myform.after(currentVal + '<br>');
});
myform.hide();
```